# Returning values from thread specific code using boost threads

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using C++ boost library threads like this

```
MyThread alarm();
boost::thread thrd(alarm);
if (thrd.timed_join(boost::posix_time::seconds(timeout)))
{
    cout << alarm.modified_var << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << alarm.modified_var << endl;
}
```

modified_var is changed inside MyThread class but when I print it later after synchronization point i get unitialized value of modified_var. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because the `alarm`-object is [copied when passed to the `thread` constructor](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.callable_constructor). The solution is to wrap it in a [`boost::ref`](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/ref.html):

```
boost::thread thrd(boost::ref(alarm));
```

Comment: but why exactly constructor accepts a reference but then copies the object?

Comment: @Sergej: The contructor actually takes a callable by value. `boost::ref` wraps a reference in a type that can be copied while still referring to the same object.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was looking at private constructor in boost header file